# Sorting Date column on Client side

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, slds

I have an array of objects `{Object, Object, ...}`. I want to sort the Date column. Let's say below are some cases:

```
Case-1: { "2020-05-26", "2018-06-26", "2019-06-15" ,"2018-07-05" ,"2018-07-05", "2017-08-15"}
Case-2: { "2020/05/26", "2018/06/26", "2019/06/15" ,"2018/07/05" ,"2018/07/05", "2017/08/15"}
Case-3: { "2020.05.26", "2018.06.26", "2019.06.15" ,"2018.07.05" ,"2018.07.05", "2017.08.15"}
Case-4: { "20.05.26", "18.06.26", "19.06.15" ,"18.07.05" ,"18.07.05", "17.08.15"}
```

Below is the code written and I am able to sort it correctly for Case-2 but not for Case-1.

```
listOfentities.sort(function(a,b){
                    x = a[field];
                    y = b[field];
                   (x > y)? alert('x is greater than y'):(x < y ? alert('x is less than y'): alert('x is equal to y'));
                   console.log(x);
                   console.log(y);
                   return (x == y)? 0 : (sortAsc?-1:1)*(x > y? -1 : 1);
});
```

Can anyone please let me know where I am wrong?

Comment: Looks okay to me. What results are you getting?

Comment: @sfdcfox My bad It is working fine!! I took it in wrong way.

Comment: @sfdcfox 
All the dates in these formats starting with years are successfully sorted (yyyy-mm-dd ; yyyy/mm/dd ; yyyy.mm.dd ; yy.mm.dd)

But the formats starting with dates are not sorted properly( dd/mm/yyyy ; dd-mm-yyyy ; dd.mm.yyyy ; dd.mm.yy)

Example: { "26.05.2020", "26.06.2018", "15.06.2019" ,"05.07.2018" ,"05.07.2018", "15.08.2017"}
Output for this is not correct: (Desc)
{26.06.2018 , 26.05.2020 , 15.08.2017 , 15.06.2019 , 05.07.2018 ,05.07.2018}

Can you let me know my mistake?

Comment: The problem is that your "dates" are not [`Date`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) when you sort them.

Comment: @martin From the array of objects I get the Start Date and I use that.
What I am planning to do for DMY format is: 
dd.mm.yyyy ----- a[column].split('.').reverse().join()
dd/mm/yyyy ----- a[column].split('/').reverse().join()
dd-mm-yyyy ----- a[column].split('-').reverse().join()
But how to do all this in single line? Is this what you are mentioning? Please let me know

Comment: the only difference between those statements is in the argument provided to the split method, so you could combine them like this: `.split(/[-./]/).reverse().join()`

Comment: @martin Got it!! This will work for DMY format :) What condition should i specify for DMY or YMD format in if loop here?
Also you are mentioning something about Dates. Can you let me know how to use that?

Comment: What I was getting at is that if you used your date strings to construct date objects, the relational operators would implicitly call the valueOf method on those objects when making the comparison, which for Javascript Dates, would produce a millisecond timestamp which would properly sort out your values. Sorting your values as strings would also work though.